# iBeacones broadcast and listen at the same time

Tags: objective-c, ibeacon, btle

I have a script that turns the phone into a beacon and broadcasts its location using the iBeacons functionality. Here is the very simple code:

```
 //--- Start broadcasting
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"some-static-uuid"];
 self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid major:@"1" minor:@"2" identifier:@"com.myidentifer"];
```

On the SAME device, I want to listen for other beacons close by... So I have a similar script running and I star the "ranging" service.

Problem that I am running into is that it doesn't seem to work if I broadcast and listen at the same time... I have a script running that alternates the listening and broadcasting, and this seems to work "ok"... But I would really rather have these functions running simultaneously.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is an hardware limitation. If the bluetooth in the device is broadcasting an ibeacon signal (peripheral mode), it is operating in a different mode and it cannot at the same time scan for ibeacons.

Comment: That makes sense and it was what I thought. Thanks for the info! Is this by any chance backed up in the documentation anywhere?

Comment: I dont find documentation talking about that.
This guy found a way to work the two modes "at the same time", but de device cannot discover himself, so it should be work alternately http://stackoverflow.com/a/20228897/3482000