# iBeacon - iOS Region Monitoring and Region Advertising simultaneously

Tags: iphone, ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, clregion

I am trying to use

```
[self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:self.myBeaconData];
```

to advertise UUID and beacon’s identifying information and also monitoring same UUID with different minor and major using

```
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.myBeaconRegion];
```

but I am not able to fulfill this requirement of using ***same Device(iPhone) as receiver as well as broadcaster(advertiser)***

Can anyone help me to create a iPhone Device to behave as a Broadcaster(Advertise an UUID, for example "**A77A1B68-49A7-4DBF-914C-760D07FBB87B**") and at same time behave as Receiver to Monitor same region for other beacon having same UUID "**A77A1B68-49A7-4DBF-914C-760D07FBB87B**".

Comment: check this :- http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-programming-ibeacons-tutorial/

Comment: I checked this one. but they have shown two apps, one for Broadcasting and another one as Receiver. I am trying to make One app performing both tasks simultaneously.

Comment: Try this approuch to get that working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351856/ios-corebluetooth-ibeacon-advertise-an-ibeacon-and-a-peripheral-service-concu/20228897#20228897

Comment: @Sandro I tried this one and it is working until the app is active, in other states it is not giving desired result

Comment: Did you enable background location?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot broadcast an iBeacon and simultaneously monitor for iBeacons. This is current as of iOS 7 and iOS 8 Beta 4. This is not likely to change any time soon. This is also why all tutorials show 2 apps and 2 devices usually.

Comment: Actually it is working simultaneously as per solution provided as per @Sandro. but sometime its failing.

Comment: If the limitation is that the device can't detect itself, it essentially doesn't work correctly. To do anything with that setup, still requires a 2nd device to trigger any of the events.

Comment: No Brother I just Implemented this thing and its working fine without any issue. I will share the Demo app if you want.

Comment: Could you show a demo app Mrug. I am trying  to do similar thing.